# Streamlit and Python, The problem of not using the return value of the function inside the other function and undesired path visual

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, callback, streamlit

The code:

```
#Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import fitz 
import io
import streamlit as st

global path_input_0    #HERE ASSIGNMENTS-------------------------------
path_input_0=""
path_input_last=""

def login():
  
    # interface codes for the login screen
    path_input_0 =st.text_input("File Path:", "Please enter the path to the folder containing the Abstract_Account_Web_App.py file")
    st.write(path_input_0)
    global proceed
    if st.button("Proceed"):
        st.session_state["page"] = "main"
        st.balloons()
        st.experimental_rerun()
    return path_input_0


def main():
    # interface codes for the main screen
    
    pathz=path_input_last+"/Bankomat Alışveriş Özeti.pdf"
    st.write("path1:",pathz)
    file_names = [r'%s' % pathz]
    st.write(file_names)


if __name__=='__main__':
               
    if "page" not in st.session_state:
                  st.session_state["page"] = "login"
    
    if st.session_state["page"] == "login":
                 
                  path_input_last=login()
                  st.write("last:",path_input_last)
                  
     
    elif st.session_state["page"] == "main":
                  st.balloons()
                  main()
```

**Main screen:** (First login screen, after main screen)
[image]

Hello friends, I’m trying to take the path from the login screen and use it on the main screen. The login function returns the path_input_0 from the user. But I can’t get this output and use it in the main function `Pathz=path_input_last+“/Bankomat Alışveriş Özeti.pdf”`. Main function’s path_input_last comes as null.(“”) So it just prints path1 as /Bankomat Alışveriş Özeti.pdf. I don’t want that. The full file path is not coming.
Secondly, `file_names = [r'%s' %pathz]` looks weird in the interface. My goal here was to take the file path as a variable and read it properly.

If I call login inside the main function again, I can get the variables I want, but this time the problem of calling the two interfaces together arises. It breaks this as my goal is to fetch the interfaces in order

How Can I solve these problems? Could you explain the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def login():
    # interface codes for the login screen
    # (css,buttons,background,input area etc )
    path_input_0 = st.text_input(
        "File Path:",
        "Please enter the path to the folder containing the Abstract_Account_Web_App.py file",
        key="PATH_INPUT_LAST",
    )
    st.write(path_input_0)
    global proceed
    if st.button("Proceed"):
        st.session_state["page"] = "main"
        st.balloons()
        st.experimental_rerun()



def main():
    
    file0 = st.session_state["PATH_INPUT_LAST"]+"/Bankomat Alışveriş Özeti.csv"
    st.write(file0)
    if(os.path.exists(file0) and os.path.isfile(file0)):
      os.remove(file0)
      print("file was deleted as preprocessing")
    else:
      print("file was not found to delete")
    
    # interface codes for the main screen
    # (css,input,buttons etc.)
    def set_texts(pdf_files:list):
        print("starting to text process")
        #This function reads pdf and gets "CRC-32" components as texts
        for pdf_file in pdf_files:
            with fitz.open(pdf_file) as doc:
                text = ""
                for page in doc:
                    new_text = page.get_text()
                    text += new_text
            
                    return text
  



    pathz = st.session_state["PATH_INPUT_LAST"] + "/Bankomat Alışveriş Özeti.pdf"
    st.write("path1:", pathz)
   
    file_names = r'%s' % pathz
    
    st.write(file_names)
    set_texts([file_names])
   
 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "page" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state["page"] = "login"

    if st.session_state["page"] == "login":
        login()

    elif st.session_state["page"] == "main":
        st.balloons()
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I had to shrink some parts of the code with **...** so it could be somehow readable and straight forward. Looking at your code, you are calling two functions separately with conditions. when you pay attention to where you called the `login()` is way at the bottom which is also outside the `main()`. With your approach, yon can only get the **path** when you call the `login()` in the `main()` and at the right place, otherwise you will have to assign an independent variable and tell `login()` to pass the path to that variable so that `main()` will know where to look for the **path** when it needs it.

```py
list_path_input_last = []

def login():
    ...

    path_input_0 = st.text_input("File Path:", "Please enter the path to the folder containing the Abstract_Account_Web_App.py file")
    if path_input_0 is not None:
        list_path_input_last.append(path_input_0)
    st.write(path_input_0)
    ...

def main(): 
    for path in list_path_input_last:
      
        pathz = path + "/Bankomat Alışveriş Özeti.pdf"
        st.write("path1:",pathz)
        file_names = [r'%s' % pathz]
        st.write(file_names)
```

`login()` here is not called in the `main()` that is why you don't get the path.

```py
if st.session_state["page"] == "login":
    path_input_last=login() # is not in the main()
    st.write("last:",path_input_last)
```

Comment: I tried the code above, but when I press the proceed button, the path did not appear in the 2nd interface (I use the main function to switch to the second interface), only a blank screen appears. Last section like this: if __name__=='__main__':
               
    if "page" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state["page"] = "login"
    if st.session_state["page"] == "login":
         path_input_last=login() # is not in the main()
         st.write("last:",path_input_last)
    elif st.session_state["page"] == "main":
       st.balloons()         
       main()